# Tridion UI 2012 -Error 424 occurred while rendering the page Object required: 'SiteEdit

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

One of my application was upgraded from SiteEdit 1.3 SP2 to SiteEdit 2009.Now i am upgrading it again to Tridion UI  2012. I restored both the DLL's cm_SiteEdit.dll and cc_SiteEdit2.dll. 
In code inside the templates,objects "SiteEdit" and "SiteEdit2" are accessibly used.Object "SiteEdit2" is initialized properly and object "SiteEdit" is throwing below error  -

> Error 424 occurred while rendering the page Object required:
>   'SiteEdit'.

Is it possible to go with this implementation to save the development efforts ? if yes , please help to resolve the issue. otherwise your valuable suggestions/inputs would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 7):

This error is typically thrown because you haven't registered "SiteEdit" as a Script Extension in the SDL Tridion Content Manager configuration. From your description, I gather that it should point to the 1.3 script extension.

Once you do, be sure to restart the Tridion COM+ package for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Peter has already answered your question still I would like to recommend not to use old SiteEdit object. You should update the template code as per Tridion UI 2012.